# Using javascript, delete the original file after saving it in a different name?

Tags: javascript, adobe, delete-file, acrobat

I'm using adobe acrobat to make a form and I require the user to save once as a incomplete file, and the second time as a complete form. How do I use javascript to delete the first incomplete file once the second completed form is saved?

I have a folder level script for "mySaveAs" function

This is the script to save the incomplete file

```
var directory = "/c/adobeform/" 
if (typeof(mySaveAs) == "function") { 
  mySaveAs(this, directory,"incomplete_" + this.getField("Filename").value); 
} else { 
  app.alert("Missing Save Function. Please contact forms administrator "); 
}
```

I need help for the second script to save the second file and delete the first file. I want to save the completed form in the same path but remove the "incomplete".

This is what I have so far

```
    // determine the directory path for the current document 
    var directory = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("/"));

    if (typeof(mySaveAs) == "function") { 
      mySaveAs(this, directory,this.getField("Filename").value); 
    } else { 
      app.alert("Missing Save Function. Please contact forms administrator "); 
    }

var file = ("/c/adobeform/incomplete_" + this.getfield("Filename"));

if(file.exists()) {
  file.delete();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please flow link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask this will help you to stage question in better way to get quick help.

Answer (score 1):

Acrobat JavaScript cannot delete a file. You're going to need to rethink your process.

Comment: What about overwriting the first saved file?

Comment: Yes - That is possible using JavaScript but there are security restrictions that you'll need to work out. Acrobat won't just let you overwrite a file without user permission.